# JavaScript event handler function not working when i supply string to its parameter list

Tags: javascript

im trying to pass the variable "image" to the onclick event handler function. When "image" variable is something like "1111" it works, but when i give some string value to it like "11sfrl" or just pure string without numeric characters, the event handler function is not called then. I've tried to wrap it to double quotes on the parameter list but didn't help.

```
image="ssss";
element4 = $('<div id="elem'+element.id+'" style="position:absolute;width:38px;height:24px;left:123px;margin:2px;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:red;" onclick="deletefromcart(this.id,'+image+');"></div>').appendTo(element);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest doing this with jQuery functions, rather than with a long string of HTML:

```
element4 = $('<div id="elem' + element.id + '" />')
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '38px',
        height: '24px',
        left: '123px',
        margin: '2px',
        borderWidth: '1px',
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderColor: 'red'
    })
    .click(function(){
        deletefromcart(this.id, image);
    })
    .appendTo(element);
```

This will be more reliable than constructing a string.

Comment: Excellent example how properly using jQuery can greatly simplify your code. You could also write `$('<div id="elem' + element.id + '" />')` as `$('<div />', {id: 'elem' + element.id})` to make the quotes somewhat easier to read but all in all this is a great example on how you can take a virtually unreadable line of JavaScript wrapped in HTML wrapped in JavaScript that is a quoting and escaping nightmare spanning horizontally four screens and write it as a clear, readable, easy to understand and easy to **maintain** piece of code, that you can just look at and know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `'onclick="deletefromcart(this.id,'+image+');">'` becomes: `onclick="deletefromcart(this.id,IMAGEURL);">`. You probably want:

```
onclick="deletefromcart(this.id,\''+image+'\');"
```

Comment: Thank you man you are a genious it is working like miracle. But tell me one thing when i used double quotes instead of escaped single quotes why didn't that worked too? Is it only possible to use single quotes on a parameter list or what?

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer :) It is only possible to use single quotes for parameters when your attribute is in double quotes. If your attributes had been single quoted, you could have used double quotes for the parameter, like this: `onclick=\'deletefromcart(this.id,"'+image+'");\'`